# How to remove highlighting from keywords in comment text in markdown fenced code block

Tags: git, comments, markdown, pandoc

I have a markdown file with a fenced code block that contains some lines of the form:

```
int var;               // A comment on what var is used for
```

Even though the keyword "for" appears in a comment, it still gets a syntax highlight. Is there a way to ensure that syntax keywords in comments don't get highlighted? Or, as a more general fix, is there an "escape sequence" in markdown that specifies that a term in a code block is not to be highlighted? I can change the code block to an indented-format (without syntax highlighting), but I would prefer to keep the highlighting where it's appropriate.

The wording of my comments is important for what I'm working on, so please assume that rewording to avoid "for," "if," etc. is not an option.

This problem appears both when rendering .md files on a git-like interface and when using pandoc to convert .md to .pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify what language the [pandoc syntax highlighting](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#syntax-highlighting) should be in. Not sure what language has backspace comment though... but for example:

````
``` {.haskell}
qsort [] = []
```
````